# How to resolve this issue with HTML menu in ASP.NET WebForms application?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap-3, webforms

I am new ASP.NET WebForms developer and I am using ASP.NET 4.5. I am struggling right now with developing the menu. I am using Bootstrap as the main style for the UI of my application. Also, I would like to keep using the normal HTML ul tags for developing this menu. However, I am struggling now with configuring the links in this menu. 
The website navigation is as follows:

```
Home
About 
Contact
Admin > Service Management
      > User Managment
```

The first three pages; home, about and contact are under the same folder called Pages. Under Pages folder, there is another folder called Admin. This folder includes ServiceManagement and UserManagement pages. The problem which I am struggling with is that when the user is browsing ServiceManagement or UserManagement and he clicks on the link to Home page from the top menubar, he will got an error and the link will look like the following:

http://localhost:61090/Pages/Pages/About.aspx

Here's the code of the Menu:

```
    <div class="container">
                        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
                            <div class="navbar-header">
                                <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".js-navbar-collapse">
                                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                </button>
                                <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
                                    <img src="../Assets/images/logo.png" alt="">
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse js-navbar-collapse">
                                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                                    <li><a href="../Pages/Default.aspx" class="active">Home</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="../Pages/About.aspx">About</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="../Pages/Contact.aspx">Contact</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown mega-dropdown">
                                        <a href="~/Pages/Admin/AdminPage.aspx" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Admin                     <span class="fa fa-angle-down"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu mega-dropdown-menu row">
                                            <li class="col-sm-3">
                                                <ul>
                                                    <li class="">
<a href="~/Pages/Admin/ServiceManagement.aspx">Service Management</a></li>
                            <li class="">User Management</li>
                        </ul>
    </li>
    </ul>
    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <!-- /.nav-collapse -->
                        </nav>
                    </div>
```

So **how can I resolve this issue?**

Answer (score 0):

Change your HTML markup from:

```
<a href="../Pages/About.aspx">About</a>
```

To

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="lnkAbout" runat="server" Text="About" NavigateUrl="~/Pages/About.aspx"></asp:HyperLink>
```

The key point to take from this, is that the `NavigateUrl` property uses a path relative to the root of your web application `~/`. This makes it simple to reference pages/content from your ASPX pages etc.

**HTML based approach**

You could try to set the following in your `Admin` HTML files.

```
<HEAD>
   <!-- Removed for brevity -->

   <BASE href="http://yourURL/Pages/Admin">

   <!-- Removed for brevity -->
 </HEAD>
```

I am not 100% certain on this one so you will need to try it on your own (in the ServiceManagement and UserManagement pages only).

Comment: Thanks for your help. Is there a way to keep it as HTML `<a>` instead of using an ASP.NET Hyperlink?

Comment: You would need to post your file/solution directory information so we can see your structure. Also, you could try using `<a href="/Pages/About.aspx">About</a>` but this may cause issues when running from IIS Express / IIS locally.

Comment: @user3107976 Can you please accept one of the answers?

Answer (score 0):

Place the attribute `runat="server"` inside the `<a>` tag.

For your href value, start with `"~/"` to identify the application root. [See ASP.NET Web Site Paths](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178116(v=vs.100).aspx).

e.g. `<a runat="server" href="~/Pages/About.aspx">About</a>`

You can also use the same format to link your image file:

e.g. `<img runat="server" src="~/Assets/images/logo.png" alt="">`